# Need to toggle divs via button click on each row of a table independantly. Can anybody suggest some clean jquery to use?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking to make a table with 7-10 row and 2 columns. 1 Column for buttons and 1 column for text.

Upon clicking the button in a specific row, it will then toggle from 1 block of text to another block of text in that same row.

Example of the HTML:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <a class="button1" href="#">Reveal Tips</a>
            </td>
            <td>
            <div class="textshown1">
            <p>Text being initially displayed</p>
            </div>

            <div class="texthidden1" style="display: none;">
            <p>Text to be displayed after onclick funtion</p>
            </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <a class="button2" href="#">Reveal Tips</a>
            </td>
            <td>
            <div class="textshown2">
            <p>Text being initially displayed</p>
            </div>

            <div class="texthidden2" style="display: none;">
            <p>Text to be displayed after onclick funtion</p>
            </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and Jquery:

```
$('.button1').on('click', function() {
$('.textshown1').hide(0);
$('.texthidden1').show(0);
});

$('.button2').on('click', function() {
$('.textshown2').hide(0);
$('.texthidden2').show(0);
});
```

I'm looking for a cleaner way of accomplishing this without having to make a separate onclick function for each button/row.

Can anybody give a suggestion? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the same class name to avoid adding the event handler multiple times. then use jquery like:

```
$(".reveal-button").on("click", function(e) {
  $(this).parents("tr").find(".textshown").hide(0);
  $(this).parents("tr").find(".texthidden").show(0);
});
```

all buttons will have 'reveal-button' class and on click of that, find the ascendant `tr` node of the clicked button, then find the descendant div (with specific class name) of the tr node then hide/show the div.

In case the rows are dynamically generated then change the event subscription call to:
`$("table").on("click", ".reveal-button", function(e) {`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `data` attributes to add `id` on each button and `textshown` and `texthidden` elements. Then, you can simply find those `div` elements using `jQuery` like below-

```js
jQuery('.reveal-button').click(function (e) {
  let id = $(this).data("id");
  jQuery(".textshown[data-id="+id+"]").toggle();
  jQuery(".texthidden[data-id="+id+"]").toggle();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
              <a class="reveal-button" data-id="1" href="#">Reveal Tips</a>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class="textshown" data-id="1">
                <p>Text being initially displayed</p>
              </div>
              <div class="texthidden" data-id="1" style="display: none;">
                <p>Text to be displayed after onclick funtion</p>
              </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
              <a class="reveal-button" data-id="2" href="#">Reveal Tips</a>
            </td>
            <td>
            <div class="textshown" data-id="2">
            <p>Text being initially displayed</p>
            </div>

            <div class="texthidden" data-id="2" style="display: none;">
            <p>Text to be displayed after onclick funtion</p>
            </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Another way to do this can be by traversing through the DOM using `[parent][1]` and `next` selectors. For example-

```
jQuery('.reveal-button').click(function (e) {
    $(this).parent().next().find('.textshown').toggle();
    $(this).parent().next().find('.texthidden').toggle();
})
```